# Join Two csv file to one Csv file Based matching Column

Tags: php, linux, csv

I have 2 csv file,

first.csv

```
 Name  desc date

 raj   test  1-2-2015
 kumar test  2-2-205
```

secound.csv :

```
 Name   Text

 raj   Testvalue
```

I need to join this two csv file , if **name** are matching then, "Text" filed to add in **first.csv** file.

output.csv

```
 Name  desc   date     Text

  raj  Test  1-2-2015  TestValue
```

Suggest me how to do this in php or linux cmd.

Comment: If my solution is working, then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
join  <(cat first.csv) <(cat second.csv)
```